# Creating a settings menu to change notification settings

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-preferences, android-menu

I am trying to create a preferences menu to allow users to change the volume/notifications settings for the application. I'm already getting errors inside the PreferenceChangeListener. (see below). I was trying to use a PreferenceChangeListener to implement onSharedPreferenceChangeListener by calling ApplySettings(). Is this the recognized way to do this?

```
private class PreferenceChangeListener implements onSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences SP, String key){
    ApplySettings();
}
}

public void ApplySettings(){
    String notifications_setting = SP.getString(prefUpdateFrequency, Off);      
}
```

Inside Settings, the list preference options have the key "prefUpdateFrequency."

I have stored the values inside an arrays.xml:

```
<resources>
 <string-array name="updateNotifications">
    <item name="0">Off</item>
    <item name="1">Silent</item>
    <item name="2">Vibrate Only</item>
    <item name="3">Noise Enabled</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="updateNotificationValues">
    <item name="0">Off</item>
    <item name="1">Silent</item>
    <item name="2">Vibrate Only</item>
    <item name="3">Noise Enabled</item>
        </string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is that you store the value of setting in a sharedPreference; then you can load the preference when your activity start.

You can have a look : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html